# QWebView App crashes when loading (with logs) and painting

Tags: c++, qt, crash, qpainter

> 0 WTFCrash    assertions.cpp  345 0x10f50517
>   1 WTF::OwnPtr::operator->   ownptr.h    72  0xffbc8cd
>   2 WebCore::BitmapTextureImageBuffer::updateContents   texturemapperimagebuffer.cpp    62  0x109cb865
>   3 WebCore::TextureMapperTile::updateContents  texturemappertile.cpp   70  0x109cfdb5
>   4 WebCore::TextureMapperTiledBackingStore::updateContents texturemappertiledbackingstore.cpp  147 0x109c1831
>   5 WebCore::GraphicsLayerTextureMapper::updateBackingStoreIfNeeded graphicslayertexturemapper.cpp  624 0x103b852e
>   6 WebCore::GraphicsLayerTextureMapper::flushCompositingStateForThisLayerOnly  graphicslayertexturemapper.cpp  444 0x103b79b4
>   7 WebCore::GraphicsLayerTextureMapper::flushCompositingState  graphicslayertexturemapper.cpp  591 0x103b78c7
>   8 WebCore::GraphicsLayerTextureMapper::flushCompositingState  graphicslayertexturemapper.cpp  596 0x103b796f
>   9 WebCore::GraphicsLayerTextureMapper::flushCompositingState  graphicslayertexturemapper.cpp  596 0x103b796f
>   10    WebCore::GraphicsLayerTextureMapper::flushCompositingState  graphicslayertexturemapper.cpp  596 0x103b796f
>   11    WebCore::GraphicsLayerTextureMapper::flushCompositingState  graphicslayertexturemapper.cpp  596 0x103b796f
>   12    WebCore::GraphicsLayerTextureMapper::flushCompositingState  graphicslayertexturemapper.cpp  596 0x103b796f
>   13    WebCore::RenderLayerCompositor::flushPendingLayerChanges    renderlayercompositor.cpp   399 0x1010ef84
>   14    WebCore::FrameView::flushCompositingStateForThisFrame   frameview.cpp   937 0xffda850
>   15    WebCore::FrameView::paintContents   frameview.cpp   3613    0xffdd1a0
>   16    QWebFrameAdapter::renderRelativeCoords  qwebframeadapter.cpp    539 0xfb0787c
>   17    QWebFrame::render   qwebframe.cpp   644 0x60e96a96
>   18    QWebFrame::render   qwebframe.cpp   655 0x60e96a54
>   19    QWebView::paintEvent    qwebview.cpp    833 0x60ea34e8
>   20    QWidget::event  qwidget.cpp 8114    0x778e9b5c
>   21    QWebView::event qwebview.cpp    732 0x60ea30dc
>   22    QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    3500    0x778a1dde
>   23    QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3465    0x7789fdbe
>   24    QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    935 0x66412d04
>   25    QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent  qcoreapplication.h  240 0x66528938
>   26    QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget  qwidget.cpp 5151    0x778ef4f1
>   27    QWidgetBackingStore::doSync qwidgetbackingstore.cpp 1180    0x778b2a74
>   28    QWidgetBackingStore::sync   qwidgetbackingstore.cpp 1027    0x778b0f40
>   29    QWidgetPrivate::syncBackingStore    qwidget.cpp 1693    0x778f13e1
>   30    QWidget::event  qwidget.cpp 8252    0x778e9ee2
>   31    QWebView::event qwebview.cpp    732 0x60ea30dc
>   32    QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    3500    0x778a1dde
>   33    QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3465    0x7789fdbe
>   34    QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    935 0x66412d04
>   35    QCoreApplication::sendEvent qcoreapplication.h  237 0x6641c0d9
>   36    QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents   qcoreapplication.cpp    1539    0x66413ce6
>   37    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents  qcoreapplication.cpp    1397    0x664117c2
>   38    QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::sendPostedEvents    qwindowsguieventdispatcher.cpp  88  0x5223bf1
>   39    qt_internal_proc    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    423 0x664aa392
>   40    _InternalCallWinProc    USER32      0x77467834
>   41    UserCallWinProcCheckWow USER32      0x77467a9a
>   42    DispatchMessageWorker   USER32      0x7746988e
>   43    DispatchMessageW    USER32      0x774698f1
>   44    QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    757 0x664aac85
>   45    QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents   qwindowsguieventdispatcher.cpp  80  0x5223b1c
>   46    QEventLoop::processEvents   qeventloop.cpp  137 0x6640eb8c
>   47    QEventLoop::exec    qeventloop.cpp  212 0x6640ed82
>   48    MainWindow::waitForLoad mainwindow.cpp  345 0xe10fd2
>   49    MainWindow::thread  mainwindow.cpp  460 0xe0729b
>   50    MainWindow::on_GoButton_clicked mainwindow.cpp  99  0xe04b32
>   51    MainWindow::qt_static_metacall  moc_mainwindow.cpp  72  0xe2f5a8
>   52    MainWindow::qt_metacall moc_mainwindow.cpp  100 0xe2f53b
>   53    QMetaObject::metacall   qmetaobject.cpp 309 0x6641ede0
>   54    QMetaObject::activate   qobject.cpp 3695    0x6645da56
>   55    QMetaObject::activate   qobject.cpp 3546    0x6645d411
>   56    QAbstractButton::clicked    moc_qabstractbutton.cpp 294 0x77d4809b
>   57    QAbstractButtonPrivate::emitClicked qabstractbutton.cpp 544 0x779f6657
>   58    QAbstractButtonPrivate::click   qabstractbutton.cpp 536 0x779f5bdb
>   59    QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent  qabstractbutton.cpp 1141    0x779f5042
>   60    QWidget::event  qwidget.cpp 7962    0x778e957c
>   61    QAbstractButton::event  qabstractbutton.cpp 1098    0x779f4ba1
>   62    QPushButton::event  qpushbutton.cpp 682 0x77ab6f1b
>   63    QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    3500    0x778a1dde
>   64    QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3067    0x7789e5ee
>   65    QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    935 0x66412d04
>   66    QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent  qcoreapplication.h  240 0x66528938
>   67    QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent qapplication.cpp    2540    0x778a3123
>   68    QWidgetWindow::handleMouseEvent qwidgetwindow.cpp   505 0x779249f1
>   69    QWidgetWindow::event    qwidgetwindow.cpp   180 0x77923c0e
>   70    QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    3500    0x778a1dde
>   71    QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    2953    0x7789dfb7
>   72    QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    935 0x66412d04
>   73    QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent  qcoreapplication.h  240 0x66528938
>   74    QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent   qguiapplication.cpp 1701    0x10c82af
>   75    QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent    qguiapplication.cpp 1502    0x10ca1d9
>   76    QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents  qwindowsysteminterface.cpp  579 0x10acad1
>   77    QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::sendPostedEvents    qwindowsguieventdispatcher.cpp  89  0x5223c01
>   78    qt_internal_proc    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    423 0x664aa392
>   79    _InternalCallWinProc    USER32      0x77467834
>   80    UserCallWinProcCheckWow USER32      0x77467a9a
>   81    DispatchMessageWorker   USER32      0x7746988e
>   82    DispatchMessageW    USER32      0x774698f1
>   83    QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    757 0x664aac85
>   84    QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents   qwindowsguieventdispatcher.cpp  80  0x5223b1c
>   85    QEventLoop::processEvents   qeventloop.cpp  137 0x6640eb8c
>   86    QEventLoop::exec    qeventloop.cpp  212 0x6640ed82
>   87    QCoreApplication::exec  qcoreapplication.cpp    1188    0x66411312
>   88    QGuiApplication::exec   qguiapplication.cpp 1437    0x10c6e78
>   89    QApplication::exec  qapplication.cpp    2746    0x7789dab9
>   90    main    main.cpp    10  0xe02c18     91 WinMain qtmain_win.cpp  131 0xe3145a
>   92    __tmainCRTStartup   crtexe.c    528 0xe30872
>   93    WinMainCRTStartup   crtexe.c    377 0xe3063d
>   94    BaseThreadInitThunk KERNEL32        0x772f919f
>   95    __RtlUserThreadStart    ntdll       0x7771a8cb
>   96    _RtlUserThreadStart ntdll       0x7771a8a1

It outputs

> QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2 ASSERTION
>   FAILED: m_ptr
>   c:\work\build\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtwebkit\Source\WTF\wtf/OwnPtr.h(72) :
>   WTF::OwnPtr::operator ->

In function

```
bool MainWindow::waitForLoad(QWebView& view)
{
    QEventLoop loopLoad;
    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &loopLoad, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(&view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &timer, SLOT(stop()));
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &loopLoad, SLOT(quit()));
    timer.start(timeout);
    loopLoad.exec();
    if(timer.isActive())
    {
        timer.stop();
        view.stop();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

On the line "loopLoad.exec();"

Please help me. What's wrong with my code? Or how to fix that? I ready to disable any user-controls, css, images and ect. Advise me how to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer! To fix this problem, enable autoload images!